# How to get all list youtube channel by API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How to get all list youtube channel by API? Popular, categories...

ex:

1. Music
2. Sport
3. News
4. BostonEnglish
5. etc

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if there's a category for Boston English. But, for the general categories you've mentioned like Music, News, Sports, there's definitely a way to do that. Use this list as [video category guide](https://gist.github.com/dgp/1b24bf2961521bd75d6c).

Try this on your browser:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&videoCategoryId=17&maxResults=50&key=SERVER_API_KEY_HERE

It will show you a list of channels under Sports.

Just change the `videoCategoryId=17` part depending on which category you like. So if it's music, use `videoCategoryId=10` and so on. `maxResults=50` is set to 50, meaning it will display 50 results per page

Comment: It is loading video in channel.

Comment: "It is loading video in channel?" What do you mean by that? I gave you a server request that returns all channels according to your preferred category (music, sports, news, etc).

Comment: Can you rephrase the question what it is you're really trying to do?